# Memcached: More items than connections?

Tags: memcached

I setup memcached for saving (serialized) PHP sessions.
So everytime someone visits my site (1-n connections), a session (1 item) gets created.
I don't use memcached for anything else yet.

Question: How do I have **more** items than connections??

```
Total Connections 4013
Current Items 30
Total Items 7293
```

I thought it should be vice versa?!

Answer (score 1):

Current items are different than total items, usualy you are right, 1 session = 1 memcached object.

total_items = active + expired + deleted items

Your setup looks ok, also check your evicted items.